# How to add multiple rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, python-2.7

I have one excel sheet which having 5 different column.

[image]

As you can see in this excel in Testcase  column there are multiple similar values with version in the end like (**TC_008_035-01**, here **01** is the version).
if you will remove the version that is also fine.

Here, i want to compare two column. **Testcase** and **Result**.

if similar **Testcase** all value has **Passed** in Result column then it is **passed** but in result column at least one Testcase value has **Failed** then that should be **Failed**.
so, for this i want to add extra row for each testcase. 
if you will see the output excel you will get more clarity.

Here im giving you the data which is in list of dictionary form if you will dump into a DataFrame you will get the value.

```
[{u'Testcase': u'TC_008_035-01', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_035-02', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_035-03', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_035-04', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_036-01', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_036-02', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_036-03', u'Result': u'Failed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_036-04', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_037-01', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_037-02', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_037-03', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_037-04', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_038-01', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_038-02', u'Result': u'Failed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_038-03', u'Result': u'Failed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_038-04', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_005-01', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_005-02', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_005-03', u'Result': u'Passed'}, {u'Testcase': u'TC_008_005-04', u'Result': u'Passed'}]
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: can you copy and paste your data frame into this question for reproduction?

Comment: Yes i added the value. its in list of dictionary form you need to dump it into a Dataframe thats it

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need

**1.** Split the Testcase to get the first part (the part before '-'). I am calling it 'test_num'

```
df['test_num'] = df['Testcase'].str.split('-', expand=True)[0]
```

**2.** Group by test_num and perform a test like below

```
df.groupby('test_num').apply(lambda x: all(x.Result == 'Passed'))
```

which returns True if all are passed and False if not.

---

Here is some additional code to get you exactly what you need.

First I change the lambda expression. Then pass the data into a dataframe called df2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    df.groupby('test_num').apply(
        lambda x:pd.Series({
                            'Result':'Passed' if (all(x.Result == 'Passed')) else 'Failed'
                            }))).reset_index()
```

Notice I assigned a name 'Result' to the groupby result.

df2 has two columns. Here I rename the first column to be the same as that of the original dataframe so I can easily append it.

```
df2.rename(columns={'test_num': 'Testcase'}, inplace=True)

df_final = df.append(df2, sort=True).sort_values('Testcase').drop('test_num', axis=1)
```

The latter will add rows to the original data and sort it by Testcase so it appears just the same as your expected outcome.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but i want to add one more row for each  testcase which should be passed or failed as i mentioned in my output excel

Comment: The additional code should help you get what you want. If so, please give me a up-vote. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you can use `pandas` `df.apply` function to create a series of the root values of your `Testcase` column. I.e. `TC_008_038-01` & `TC_008_038-02` have root `TC_008_038` which is what you want to group them by.

```
df = pd.read_csv('something.csv')

root = df['Testcase'].apply(lambda x:'_'.join(x.replace('-', '_').split('_')[0:3]))
```

Next use the `pandas` `df.groupby` function to group those with the same `root` together and then use `agg(sum)` on the `Results` column for the groups to combine them all into results into one string of "PassedFailedPassedFailed" for each group. The `groupby` with `agg(sum)` returns a `pandas series` object that looks like this:

```
Root
TC_008_005    PassedPassedPassedPassed
TC_008_035    PassedPassedPassedPassed
TC_008_036    PassedPassedFailedPassed
TC_008_037    PassedPassedPassedPassed
TC_008_038    PassedFailedFailedPassed
```

You can use `.apply` on the series with a `lambda` function that determines if "Failed" is present in the string and if so sets it equal to "Failed" and if not sets it equal to "Passed". Then you can convert the series to dictionary using `dict`. All of that combined would be:

```
values = dict(df.groupby(root)['Result'].agg(sum).apply(lambda x: 'Failed' if 'Failed' in x else 'Passed'))
```

`values` dictionary:

```
{'TC_008_005': 'Passed', 'TC_008_035': 'Passed', 'TC_008_036': 'Failed', 'TC_008_037': 'Passed', 'TC_008_038': 'Failed'}
```

You can loop over the dictionary keys and items and with `numpy insert` you can add these item key pairs at certain indices in your dataframe.

```
for x, y in values.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, df[df['Testcase'].str.contains(x)].index[0], values=[x if b=='Testcase' else y if b == 'Result' else None for b in df.columns.values], axis=0), columns=df.columns.values)
```

the `df[df['Testcase'].str.contains(x)].index[0]` finds the index of the first column value that contains the root so that you insert before it. The `values=[x if b=='Testcase' else y if b == 'Result' else None for b in df.columns.values]` creates you a list of values to insert with the `Testcase` and `Result` value aligned with the columns on the original `df`.

Output:

```
         Testcase value Expected  Result
0      TC_008_035  None     None  Passed
1   TC_008_035-01    19    ActTi  Passed
2   TC_008_035-02    19    ActTI  Passed
3   TC_008_035-03     1      NoM  Passed
4   TC_008_035-04     1      NoM  Passed
5      TC_008_036  None     None  Failed
6   TC_008_036-01    19    ActTi  Passed
7   TC_008_036-02    19    ActTI  Passed
8   TC_008_036-03     1      NoM  Failed
9   TC_008_036-04     1      NoM  Passed
10     TC_008_037  None     None  Passed
11  TC_008_037-01    19    ActTi  Passed
12  TC_008_037-02    19    ActTI  Passed
13  TC_008_037-03     1      NoM  Passed
14  TC_008_037-04     1      NoM  Passed
15     TC_008_038  None     None  Failed
16  TC_008_038-01    19    ActTi  Passed
17  TC_008_038-02    19    ActTI  Failed
18  TC_008_038-03     1      NoM  Failed
19  TC_008_038-04     1      NoM  Passed
20     TC_008_005  None     None  Passed
21  TC_008_005-01    19    ActTi  Passed
22  TC_008_005-02    19    ActTI  Passed
23  TC_008_005-03     1      NoM  Passed
24  TC_008_005-04     1      NoM  Passed
```

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('something.csv')
root = df['Testcase'].apply(lambda x:'_'.join(x.replace('-', '_').split('_')[0:3]))
values = dict(df.groupby(root)['Result'].agg(sum).apply(lambda x: 'Failed' if 'Failed' in x else 'Passed'))

for x, y in values.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, df[df['Testcase'].str.contains(x)].index[0], values=[x if b=='Testcase' else y if b == 'Result' else None for b in df.columns.values], axis=0), columns=df.columns.values)
print(df)
```